# Select given value from list in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting value of a payroll name in a variable. I have to set this payroll name in a list drop down cell. If I am just putting this payroll in the cell using

```
Worksheets(sectionName).Range("B" & rowCntr).Value = payroll
```

above code.The drop-down change event does not trigger and because of this the other calculated cell does not get populated. 
Please suggest a way so that I can select the value from dropdown and dropdown change event get triggered.

Comment: Dropdown.value=.  All I think you can call the change event as if it was a sub

Comment: The dropdown is created using data validation option list. So I dont know the name of the dropdown.

Comment: AFAIK data validation drop downs cannot have a change event.  Is the event in VBA?  Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a way to get your code to run when you change value in the drop down? If so, give this a go.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range

    Set Cell = Range("YOUR DROP DOWN CELL") 'or an entire range of cells

    If Not Application.Intersect(Cell, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        ' Your Code Here

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have to trigger an event while putting data in cell.